# 'reqAnimFrame' function in Opera

Tags: opera, requestanimationframe

I tried to run the example: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/animation.html.
But it gives me following error on Opera 12+:
Uncaught exception: TypeError: 'reqAnimFrame' is not a function.

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proposed requestAnimationFrame() method is not yet implemented in Opera. It will be supported in a future version, for now you will need a JavaScript that falls back to using setTimeout() in browsers that do not support requestAnimationFrame().

The script you linked to makes no attempt to be compatible with older browsers. In fact, it event doesn't attempt to be compatible with *future* browsers that will presumably drop the prefixes and define just window.requestAnimationFrame(). It would be a good idea for the author to amend the script to fix these issues in his demo - it's not really hard to do so.